# tsql join tables with 2 ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this tables (Users and Meetings):

```
UserId | Name
   1   | John
   2   | Linda
   3   | David
```

and

```
UserId_1 | UserId_2 | MeetingDate
   1     |     2    |  15/01/2018
   3     |     2    |  17/01/2018
   1     |     3    |  19/01/2018
```

How do I select from the 2 tables in order to get in each row the Name associated to each id? I'd like to get something like this:

```
UserId_1 | UserId_2 | User_1_Name | User_2_Name | MeetingDate
   1     |     2    |    John     |    Linda    |  15/01/2018
   3     |     2    |    David    |    Linda    |  17/01/2018
   1     |     3    |    John     |    David    |  19/01/2018
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You just need two inner join:

```
SELECT m.UserId_1
    ,m.UserId_2
    ,u1.NAME
    ,u2.NAME
    ,m.MeetingDate
FROM Meetings m
INNER JOIN Users u1 ON u1.UserId = m.UserId_1
INNER JOIN Users u2 ON u2.UserId = m.UserId_2
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to alias one or both references to the table which you need to join twice...

```
SELECT
  user1.UserId     AS UserId_1,
  user2.UserId     AS UserId_2,
  user1.Name       AS User_1_Name,
  user2.Name       AS User_2_Name,
  Meetings.MeetingDate
FROM
  Meetings
INNER JOIN
  Users   AS user1
    ON user1.UserId = Meetings.UserId_1
INNER JOIN
  Users   AS user2
    ON user2.UserId = Meetings.UserId_2
```

The alias means that you can reference which instance of `Users` you're referring to without any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Meetings.UserId_1,
Meetings.UserId_2,
isnull(a.Name,'--Unknown--') User_1_Name,
isnull(b.Name,'--Unknown--') User_2_Name,
MeetingDate
from Meetings left join Users a on Meetings.UserId_1 = a.UserID
left join Users b on Meetings.UserId_2 = b.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is

```
SELECT m.UserId_1
    ,m.UserId_2
    ,(select name from Users where Users.id = m.UserId_1) as User_1_Name
    ,(select name from Users where Users.id = m.UserId_2) as User_2_Name
    ,m.MeetingDate
FROM Meetings m
```

Regards

Abdul